# Parsing a string?

Tags: android, string

So I have the following string:

```
String text = "\t\t\torder #168\n\t\t\tpaid\n\t\t\tview 4 items\n\t\t\tpicked up\n\t\t\tcomplete pickup\n\t\t\t2 stops";
```

How do I parse this string so that I always get the `2` in front of stops? I have tried the following, but it always returns `2 stops`.

```
String substr = "complete pickup";
String numberOfStops = text.substring(text.indexOf(substr) + substr.length());
numberOfStops = numberOfStops.replaceAll("^\\s+","").replaceAll("\\s+$","");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short way:

```
numberOfStops = numberOfStops.replaceAll("^\\s+","").replaceAll("\\s+$","").replace("stops","");
```

The flexible way is using Regex, and `Pattern` and `Match classes`. Let me know if you need it

Comment: Thanks so much, very quick fix.. I will accept this answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: It doesn't let you ? Weird. Upvote it aswell if you can :) Good luck